# How do I localize VersionInfo of an Inno Setup installation file?

Tags: inno-setup, versioninfo

I am creating an application that has a different name depending on the user language. So for example the software is called *"Device Emulator"* in English and *"Geräteemulation"* in German.

I want to reflect the different names in the Version Info of the setup file (right click -> Properties -> "Details" tab).
So far I have found no way in Inno Setup to specify a localized `"VersionInfo"`, neither in the online help nor on the net.

Originally I tried to use custom messages in the setup sections of which I learned I am not allowed to. See code below.

```
[Setup]
AppName={cm:ApplicationName}
AppVerName={cm:ApplicationName} V{#MYVERSION}
AppCopyright=© 2018 {#MYCOMPANY}
AppPublisher={#MYCOMPANY}
AppVersion={#MYVERSION}
AppId={cm:ApplicationName}{#MYVERSION}

VersionInfoVersion={#MYVERSION}
VersionInfoCompany={#MYCOMPANY}
VersionInfoCopyRight=(C) {#MYCOMPANY}
VersionInfoDescription={cm:ApplicationName}
VersionInfoProductName={cm:ApplicationName}
VersionInfoProductVersion={#MYVERSION}
```

I expected this to show me a property window with localized application name and version information but unfortunately it just displays `{cm:ApplicationName}` for `AppName`, `VersionInfoProductName` and `VersionInfoDescription`.

[image]

So, does any of you know how to localize this in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [Inno Setup constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) are evaluated on run/install-time. While version info is a compile-time thing (it's built into a header of the installer .exe file). So you cannot use constants in any of the `VersionInfo*` directives.

While technically, Windows .exe can include separate version info structures for different locales (languages), this is not supported by Inno Setup.

Inno Setup has only a [single placeholder](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/SetupLdr.version.rc) for the version info.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that Inno Setup is not supporting this.