# What alternative can I use in the [Setup] section instead of Custom Messages in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, message

As I have 3 languages in my application I've written this:

```
    [Setup]
    AppName={cm:ClientName}
    VersionInfoProductName={cm:ClientName}
    VersionInfoDescription={cm:ClientName} Setup
    [CustomMessages]
    en.ClientName=AB Office Client
    ru.ClientName=Клиент АБ Офис
    ua.ClientName=Клієнт АБ Офіс
```

But looks like I can't use those here because they're treated as plane text.
How should I do this then?

Comment: See [How do I localize VersionInfo of an Inno Setup installation file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55824937/850848)

Comment: So, it means that I can't do that?
I don't really understand this:
[link]https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/SetupLdrVersion.rc#L21-L31

Comment: As my answer says: *"this is not supported by Inno Setup"*.